# Information theory partition function definition

Tags: notation, information-theory

Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(mathematics)) the partition function as:

$$Z(\beta) = \sum_{x_i} \exp \left(-\beta H(x_1,x_2,\dots) \right)$$

Where $x_i$ are the values of random variables $X_i$, the function $H$ is understood to be a real-valued function on the space of states $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots\}$, while $\beta$ is a real-valued free parameter.

I don't understand what it is trying to say, since $x_i$ does not appear in the summand. Could someone clarify, please?

Comment: Quoting the same [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(mathematics)): The sum over the $x_i$ is understood to be a sum over all possible values that each of the random variables $X_i$ may take. Thus, the sum is to be replaced by an integral when the $X_i$ are continuous, rather than discrete... Isn't this clear enough?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, thanks! Strangely, I missed this part over multiple readings of the definition. Can't explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the partition function is the normalisation constant in the probability of any given state $P(x_1,x_2,...|\beta, H)$ so the sum has to be over all possible states of the system.

So, if your Hamiltonian is $H=H(x_1,x_2)$ and $X_i \in \{-1,+1\}$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$, then you have exactly four possible different states and the sum is over all of them.

There's a very nice introductory exposition in [MacKay's (free) book](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.html), chapter 31.